# How do i get a nested field to be read_only in modelserializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

currently when i send a get request i get what i want. But when i do a Post it throws an error saying `{"user": ["This field is required."]}` even though i put 'user' in read_only_fields.
heres the code:
serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
        

class SaleHistorySerializier(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()    
        
    class Meta:
        model = SaleHistory
        fields =['id', 'user', 'product', 'date_bought']
        read_only_fields  = ('user',)
        depth = 1
```

models.py

```
class SaleHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')
    product = models.ForeignKey(SaleItems, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, default=None)
    date_bought = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.product}, {self.user}, {self.id}'
```

api.py create part

```
class SaleHistoryVS(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

  
    def create(self, request):
        serializer = SaleHistorySerializier(data=request.data, many=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user = request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status= status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

how do i make it so that i get to create post request without having to user in my post data.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `user = UserSerializer()` with `user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)`

Comment: didnt work givs error: `null value in column "product_id" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: @Robins that is know a different error, and the first error you have received has been cleared. You can add `blank=True, null=True` to your `product` field in `SaleHistory` model or you can show us your POST request and whether you include a `product` or not in it.